# Appium Blank Screenshot in Real Devices

Tags: screenshot, appium

When I am taking screenshot using the below code I am getting blank screenshots. I tried putting sleep but that too is not working.

Please advice. It's not that I am getting all blank screens, I am getting few blank screens and few proper screenshots. I dont know what I am doing wrong. I didn't hear appium has any issues in taking screenshots.

Help me in figuring out a solution.

**Code:**

```
WebDriver driver1 = new Augmenter().augment(AppiumBaseTest.getAndroidDriver());
File file = ((TakesScreenshot) driver1).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(file, new File(System.getProperty("test.screenshot.dir") + href));
```

**Code:**

```
FileUtils.copyFile(((TakesScreenshot) AppiumBaseTest.getAndroidDriver()).
          getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE), new File(System.getProperty("test.screenshot.dir") + href));
```

I tried taking screenshot using appium driver also and that is also giving me the same issue of blank screenshot. Some are proper and some are blank.

I have tried giving wait for 7 seconds before each screenshot but of no use.

ThankS,
Rajit